# Autodesk Forge : How to extract data from .nwd files using model derivative API's

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have successfully retrieved model properties from the .rvt file using the Model Derivative APIs. However, our internal team is suggesting using .nwd files instead. We need guidance on how to extract the model properties from .nwd files, either through the Model Derivative APIs or any other available options. Please provide assistance on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model Derivative service can process more than [60 different file formats](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/) today, incl. Navisworks designs, and it typically generates the same kind of data on the output such as:

- thumbnails (accessible via https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/thumbnails/urn-thumbnail-GET/)
- logical hierarchies (accessible via https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-GET/)
- properties (accessible via https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ or https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/)
- 2D drawings and 3D views that can be loaded into the viewer

The logical hierarchy and properties may vary depending on the input file format but the JSON structure is always the same.